# Why didn't schoolkids use the quills like Rita Skeeter's

Tags: harry-potter

Rita Skeeter had the [quick-quote quill](http://harrypotter.wikia.com/wiki/Quick-Quotes_Quill), that seemingly

1. **Could take dictation on its own**
2. Even write on its own.

Why didn't schoolkids at Hogwarts use such quills in everyday study to:

1. **Take notes in class**
2. Help writing homework essays, at least the basic outlines.

One possible challenge may be that the quills might be expensive, but surely well-to-do kids like Harry or Draco (or those who absolutely value study like Hermione) would surely avail themselves of such.

Comment: Please note that this is specifically about normal schoolwork. I'm aware that exams may have had measures to prevent such items from being used.

Comment: Maybe Rita enchanted the pen herself and it was a one-of-a-kind thing? (I'm sure there are other examples of one-of-a-kind magical objects in HP, but can't bring any to mind.)

Comment: i know for hermione specifically she wouldn't use one of these quills in class because, actually writing the information down by hand is a great help for personal retention. having notes given to you is actually worse for studying them making them yourself. however, harry and draco who are semi lazy students ( like i was ) would use them, if they could they would haha.

Comment: @Himarm - find me a reputable academic out of universe site, and worth an answer.

Comment: @Himarm It depends on exactly how the quill determines what to write; for example, if you could dictate to it, it would be good for kids with wrist problems. Though you’d need to find a sufficiently quiet room, which might be a challenge alone.

Comment: @alexwlchan yes, for writing a paper, I would say it would be great. though, im unsure how prevalent wrist problems are in at least the younger wizard society. I would hope they had simple spells to fix a wrist problem, haha. but if not again a great choice.

Comment: the weirdest thing is looking at the school list their not even told to bring quills, parchment, or ink. (at least the ones ive seen uploaded online, no books handy) all of my school lists had those things as number 1, even in college in the what to bring to your dorm list they mentioned paper and pens.

Comment: If I remember right Rita's quill had a tendency to embellish, which might not be particularly useful in most classes (although it could be good in Divination I guess).

Comment: [Relevant](http://harrypotter.wikia.com/wiki/Auto-Answer_Quill)?

Comment: @randal'thor - yep, to an extent

Comment: There were also a few magical quills sold by Fred and George.

Comment: @randal'thor - I am not sure if the latter are film-only (I don't consider films canon at all)

Comment: ...and the answer is: Because they were being graded on *Quillmanship.*

Comment: Ron did use a magical spelling-correction quill in *Half-blood Prince*.  I think it was one of the Weasley's like @rand al'thor mentions.

Answer (score 11):

Based on study habits the general consensus from research is that taking notes (manually) and reviewing the notes is the best choice for long term retention. [abstract](http://psycnet.apa.org/journals/edu/83/2/240/)

> This experiment investigated 3 newly classified note-taking functions: encoding (take notes/no review), encoding plus storage (take notes/review notes) and external storage (absent self from lecture/review borrowed notes...Results pertaining to note-taking functions indicated that encoding plus storage was superior to encoding and to external storage for recall performance and superior to encoding for synthesis performance.

So based on this as a student such as Hermione being allowed to use a quick quotes quill would be a disadvantage. Furthermore as a teacher allowing your students to use this would also be detrimental to their learning.

Comment: I'd still like an in-universe answer as well, but this is excellently reasoned. +1 for Ravenclaw

Comment: +1 to this. My lecturers used to hate it when people turned up, left a dictaphone on the desk and left the auditorium.

Comment: @Richard i just showed up and slept

Comment: @Himarm - LOL. I once was literally banned from an entire class for showing up at the first lecture, and falling asleep on the first row.

Comment: ... (just for completeness - I was allowed to return for the final, and got an A for the final and the class).

Comment: good work @DVK, I did a similar thing and wasn't smart enough to still get a pass let alone an A! managed it the next semester when I finally showed up to classes! :-) LOL